# iOS Facebook Login Access Token refresh

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the following error when I try to login to my app using the facebook login:

> The access token is invalid since the user hasn't engaged the app in longer than 90 days.

I understand that facebook will require re-authentication after 90 days where they describe:

> Between April 9–21, 2018, tokens for users who have not actively logged into your app and granted consent to permissions in the last 90 days will expire. To refresh these user tokens, you must send people through the login process, and they must renew consent by clicking the Continue button. Renewal of consent is now required every 90 days.

I would imagine that by sending the user back to the login process they would click continue on the permissions and a new access token would be issued, but this doesn't seem to be the case, I keep getting the error as above.

Is there a way of re-authenticating the user which I am missing?

Comment: Possibly related to my question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124462/facebook-graph-api-rejects-newly-created-access-token

Comment: Have you had any joy? I've called the logout function, been issued with a new token, re-attempted the login and even then It comes back with the error. Today is not a good day for me :(

Comment: I've raised a bug with FB:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194772814474841. Quite a few people seem to have run into these issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 4/05/2018**

> Facebook have fix it.

facebook responses:

> Thanks for getting in touch. This is actually a known issue that we
>   are already tracking in another bug report.
>
> I'm going to merge your report with the existing one, so we can deal
>   with the issue in one place. Please refer to this thread for updates:
>   http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194772814474841/

Hope we'll get an update from FB today.

Comment: Did you get a response from this @Max? I got the same problem but with a test user we use for integration tests.